# Assigning Google Calendar access to all users in a group (Java)

Tags: java, api, google-calendar-api, acl, google-groups

I can create a google calendar in my Java app.

I can assign it to a particular user in my Google domain:

```
AclRule rule = new AclRule();
Scope scope = new Scope();

scope.setType("user");
scope.setValue("user1@mydomain.com");

rule.setScope(scope);
rule.setRole("reader");
```

and the created calendar appears in user1's calendars.

Yet when I try to assign some other calendar to a group (which said user1 belongs to):

```
AclRule rule = new AclRule();
Scope scope = new Scope();

scope.setType("group");
scope.setValue("group1@mydomain.com");

rule.setScope(scope);
rule.setRole("reader");
```

user1 couldn't see the created calendar in his calendar list.

But the calendar is created successfully.

Is this correct functionality? Or should I just add Acl rule **per group user**?
Or I am doing something wrong and there is other way to **assign some calendar to all the users in a group**?

Comment: This behavior works perfectly for me. I added ACL rule for user1@domain.com and all members of the group received an email with the information about that user1@domain.com shared calendar with  them. These users can see user1@domain.com calendar in "Other calendars" section. Do you still have this problem?

Comment: @MichałZiober, I was informed that MX records of those emails/users are still not changed from out organization's to gmail's, so probably users can't receive notifications about calendar sharing. Yet calendars, which are shared with a group, should appear for users anyway (without any notifications, as the user gets shared calendar successfully)? So yes, problem persists. User does not see group's calendar in his calendar list. Calendar properties show that it is shared with the group though.

Comment: What it means `MX records of those emails/users are still not changed`? How many members contains the group with which you want to share calendars?

Comment: @MichałZiober, it meant that emails of my domain were managed by other server (not Google). It probably was the problem, because when I made test app that invited my other group to calendar, I got an invitation to add it in my personal gmail inbox. So I hope it will work in the future.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I hope it will be working without any problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When assigning Calendar access to a group, every group user gets an invitation to said Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

for future people running into problems: I had this issue and it's because the creator of the calendar wasn't in the group. Make sure the "sharer" is in the google group you are sharing your calendar with